# How to avoid 503 Service Unavailable for AWS Elastic Beanstalk during .NET Application Deploy

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are using the AWS Toolkit plug in for Msvs to successfully publish updates to an EBS .NET IIS web site prototype (non-container).

However during the rollout phase while the EBS Console shows it pushing out the update, the URL User Endpoint goes down for about 60 seconds showing "HTTP Error 503 - The service is unavailable".

Is there a way around this?  The site is configured to scale from 1-3 instances but at the time of the update it was at 1 instance.

If there is more than 1 instance up during the update, is it clever enough to update them in such a manner that would avoid an outage?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.rolling-version-deploy.html). It should help you to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks!  And right next to it is the [blue/green](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html) deployments as well.